# Using Node.js library effectively

Tags: node.js

I just got started with Node.js and found that we need to RequireJS library on the backend. Also, we need to include it in view if we want to use it there. So, if I want to use d3 to manipulate some data I will specify require in backend and send the result only to front end? Or should I include it in both server side and HTML page? So is it redundant that using same library on both sides?

**For jQuery: I did**

```
npm install jquery
```

**For Bootstrap:**

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Now as the version does not match, I am including different jQuery in HTML file. Again I added d3 from scripts. Although it works, is this the proper way to design a Node.js app?

Comment: It is an important design decision to decide what computation is done on the server and what is done in the client.  If your library is doing rendering to the document window, then that must be done in the client.  If you have a choice, then it depends upon a whole host of architecture choices and app requirements which you haven't explained anything about.  As your question stands now, it's far too vague and broad.

Comment: So, we include scripts on both side. example I do npm install somelibrary and then again do /somelibrary/somelibrary.min.js. Note I am just playing through nodejs and not using it for any serious deployment.

Comment: why not use bower for client side scripts ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use npm for the client side part of the application (bootstrap included). I would recommend installing bower.

`npm install bower
bower init`

Create a .bowerrc file and put in it `{ "directory" : "public/components"}`

`bower install bootstrap --save`

Include the script in the html file.